# oracle db: how to check if a sequence exists within catalog and schema?

Tags: oracle, sequence, catalog

Oracle DB: How to check if a sequence exists within a catalog and schema?

```
select * from User_Sequences where sequence_name='Foo';
```

`ALL_SEQUENCES` has owner/schema, but does not have catalog column.

How to specify catalog and schema?

Comment: What do you mean by a "catalog"?  That's not something that has a meaning within an Oracle database.  There are API's (JDBC/ ODBC/ etc) that use the term "catalog" but if you're using one of those, you normally wouldn't be querying data dictionary tables directly, you'd be using the API for all your metadata queries.

Comment: What do you mean by "catalog?"  That does not exist in Oracle.

Comment: The concept of a catalog does exist within Oracle, but only with regards to the RMAN component.  I think @Sunnyday is confusing the oracle term schema with the generic DBMS term catalog which (loosely) is the metadata making up a schema/database

Comment: @DaveSmylie Is the hierarchical naming catalog > schema >TableFoo meaningful for oracle?

Comment: @Sunnyday I'd say Database -> Schema -> Table, but within a table, just schema -> table. ie sunnyday.users_table. The catalog is a seperate construct that holds information about rman backups + files

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in jdbc method getIndexInfo.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html